# How to use Integer NumberField in GXT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm working with GXT3 and use :

```
NumberField<Double> code = new NumberField<Double>(new DoublePropertyEditor());
```

What i can use for "NumberField< Integer >"? there no IntegerPropertyEditor, i can't do simply:

```
NumberField<Integer> code = new NumberField<Integer>(new IntegerPropertyEditor());
```

Thanks to Patrice i use as **solution**:

```
NumberField<Integer> code = new NumberField<Integer>(new NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a [IntegerPropertyEditor](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.1/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor.html) in the NumberPropertyEditor class.

You can create a custom IntegerNumberField for simplify this :

```
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.NumberPropertyEditor;

public class IntegerNumberField extends BaseNumberField<Integer>{

  public IntegerNumberField() {
    super(new NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks genius worked fine with "new NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor()"